# How to create a submit button using Java script's drag-and-drop feature?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create an object (could be a div) that acts as an HTML submit button when the user drags it to a specific location. This need to trigger an action upon release.

Comment: Where is your code ? What did you try ?

Comment: I have't tried it yet, was wondering if this is possible

Comment: Give it a try.  If you aren't successful, post what you tried and people will offer advice

Comment: @N.Cre yes it is possible.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try :)

Comment: @N.Cre Is my answer useful?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need any buttons really to get working.

You can call your js functions

-ondragstart
- ondragover
- ondrop

To run based on actions performed in your code. They can act as your triggers

See: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 drag and drop to do this work.

```js
var droppable = document.getElementById("droppable");
var draggable = document.getElementById("draggable");
var myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");

draggable.addEventListener("dragstart", function(e){ 
    e.dataTransfer.setData("text", e.target.id);
});

droppable.addEventListener("dragover", function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
});

droppable.addEventListener("drop", function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
});
```

```css
#droppable {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 4px dotted #aaa;
}

#draggable {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="droppable"></div>
<br />
<div id="draggable" draggable="true"></div>
```

Then `sumbit` your form in `drop` event like this

```
droppable.addEventListener("drop", function(){ 
    myForm.submit();
});
```

Because you can't submit form in here, i create demo in **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x974jjzo/)**.